# Как создать одноразовую ссылку?

Tags: php

Необходимо создать ссылку для клиента, которая будет не активна после захода на неё.

Comment: пишите запись в БД, у нее будет некий id, на основе этого id генерите ссылку. после захода на нее удаляете ее из БД или помечаете как использованную. И при обработке перехода конечно заглядываете в эту таблицу что бы убедится. что ссылка еще не была использована ранее

Answer (score 1):

Если нет желания/возможности использовать БД реализация с файлом-ключом. Создаете файл например d81f9c1be2e08.key, передаете клиенту ссылку с ключом по имени этого файла, после первого обращения данный файл удаляете:

```
// http://mysite.ru/info.php?key=d81f9c1be2e08

if(!is_file($_GET['key'].'.key')) die('Ссылка не активна'); // проверяем есть ли файл
unlink($_GET['key'].'.key');  // удаляем файл

/*

ВАШ КОД

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Создаем таблицу links(code string, visited integer). Генерируем ссылку:

```
$url = 'subscribe.php?code='.md5('secretword'.$link)
```

Обработка перехода по ссылке:

```
$code = md5('secretword'. $GET['code']);
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT visited FROM links WHERE code = '".$code."'";
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
if($row['visited']){
    exit();
}
$sql = "UPDATE links SET visited=1 WHERE code='".$code."'";
$conn->query($sql)

// Ваш код
```